# MySQL - How to efficiently query data across two database server without using federate tables

Tags: mysql

I'm currently working on a query that gets data from two tables on two independent MySQL servers. `Table A` keeps game user data such as player GUID, game-server. And `table B` stores logs such as game-currency consumption log with player GUID. The number of logs in `table B` is around 6 millions.

What I did so far is SELECT and CONCAT user IDs from `table A` to a very long string, and pass it to a WHERE CLAUSE to query logs from `table B`. But in some special cases the number of target IDs is more than thousands, and made my query very slow cause I'm not able to perform an INNER JOIN for filtering rows I need. And worse, sometimes the concated ID string would be too long that crashes my stored procedure.

I've googled for this problem for days, but the only solution I get is to use `federated tables`. However, I found it may be slow when the data is in a large amount and it has security risks, so I'm not really sure whether I should use federate tables.

Is there any other solution to efficiently query data from two independent MySQL servers? Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Why do you have this setup?  Is there a particular reason why you find yourself having to query across separate servers?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen The database system was done before I join the company, so I don't have choice but follow the existing architecture to do my work :(

Comment: I think you have wrong approach. The query will run slow - it's a fact. You should make a program which will do this long work. It can be multithreaded and optimized just for this certain task. You can split your main table into 100 parts and run for every part separate thread (to speed it up). if its difficult for you - just do all the work in one main thread. I think you should use C language, but not stored procedures or any exotic tools like federate tables.

Comment: Thanks your your suggestion, I’ll try this method